# AspectRatio modifier breaks min vertical sizing of containing box

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a ZStack-like implementation that allows multiple layers to be overlayed and aligned on top of each other for a server driven framework. This is working for many elements, but the aspect ratio of images breaks the sizing behavior of the zstack some how.

Here's the issue stripped down to just the compose pieces:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 300)
@Composable
fun TestZStackCompose() {
    // ZStack
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
        ,
        propagateMinConstraints = true,
    ) {
        // Aligned layer
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)) {
            // Image content
            Image(
                painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Filled.Close),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .width(40.dp)
                    .aspectRatio(ratio = 1f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The top level box represents the "ZStack" of aligned layers. This content wants to be sized to the minimum width and height of all of the aligned layers, or the forced size of the container. In this instance, the width is forced to be 300dp which overrides the `.width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)`, but the height wants to be the minimum height of the layer.

The second box represents a layer that's aligned. Every layer here wants to be sized to the size of the containing box, so all of the layers are aligned together. The sizing is achieved with the parent `propagateMinConstriants = true`, but can also be achieved by passing a `fillMaxSize()` modifier to this Box.

The content is an image sized to a width of 40dp, with the aspect ratio maintained. This should force the height of the image to be 40dp, which in turn forces the height of the inner box to be 40dp, and the outer box to be 40dp.

[image: layout showing bug]

However, what we see is the the image gets a 40dp height, driven by the aspect ratio modifier, but both boxes *also* grab the the aspect ratio modifier and are sized to 300dp / 300dp. If we change the aspect ratio to 2f, the height of the boxes is cut in half.

Few other items of interest:

- If we modify the `.width(40dp)` to `.height(40dp)`, things behave as expected, and height of both boxes becomes 40dp. But if we change the `@Preview` to fix the height, the issue re-occurs in the other dimension.
- `.fillMaxWidth(0.2f)` works, but `.fillMaxHeight(0.2f)` has the same issue. Interesting that the working dimensions are flipped in this scenario.